# The phonegap application on Android devices does not send AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, phonegap, html-framework-7

The phonegap application on Anrdoid devices does not send AJAX requests ...

Requests are in status: Pending

[image]

No javascript errors:

[image]

The same application works great on iOS devices.

In the config.xml file:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="ru.myappcompany.mobapps" version="1.1.5" versionCode="72" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    ...
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="AppendUserAgent" value="MyAppCompanyCordovaApp" />
    <preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value="MyAppCompanyCordovaApp" />
    <preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name = "android-targetSdkVersion" value = "26" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" source="npm" spec="~1.2.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" spec="~2.4.1"></plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" source="npm" spec="~1.4.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" source="npm" spec="~2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="~1.1.6" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" spec="~4.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" spec="~1.5.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" spec="~2.4.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" source="npm" spec="~1.0.7" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="~1.7.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" spec="~2.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="~1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="~3.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" spec="~2.1.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" source="npm" spec="~2.1.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner">
      <param name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="To scan barcodes." />
    </plugin>
    ...    
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
        <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
```

Comment: Are you able to communicate to your API using `cURL` (or another library) ?

Comment: I use Framwork 7. Requests are sent to him. For example:  $$.get(my_url, function (data, status, xhr) {
    $$('.page[data-page="home"] .page-content').html(data);
});

Answer (score 0):

The root certificate for SSL was installed incorrectly. That was the cause of my problem!